What type of insect/bug is this?

Bug I found on my hood of jacket After being at a friend's house.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Species ID questions are expected to include:
One or more clear Photos
A Location where the specimen was found (city/region and habitat)
An approximate Size (or photo indicating size)
Additional useful info (e.g., behavior, time of day/year, etc...)
